# Problem on Helly's theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let F be a finite family of segments in R such that among any n of them there are two mutually disjoint. We have to prove that it is possible to divide F into n− 1 family such that any two segments in one family are mutually disjoint.

So I have tried solving it in this manner as follows:
[image]

[image]

Please let me know if its a correct approach or am I missing out something.

Comment: I think you mean *mutually*, not *manually*.

Comment: Or maybe not. But, then, what do you mean by "manually disjoint"?

Comment: Yeah it's mutually disjoint.. sorry for the typo

Comment: So, why don't you fix it?

Comment: Done. Thank you for the feedback.